# How session timeout works in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, iis

I start Inetmgr

On left window I see a Treeiew 
The root node is the Server itself followed by the Default Website as a child  and in this default website I have an ASP.NET Webform application(MyApp)

My first attempt to increase the session was by going to ASP feature in iiS for "Myapp) and set the session timeout to 120 minutes( Default is 20)

Still session was timing out shortly.

They I realized Default website itself has an ASP feature. So I went there and set the Sessiontimeout   to 120 minutes.

Time out issue was remained.

Now I realize the Web sever itself has an ASP feature which set to 20 minutes.

My question is does this override the other 2 setting(Session timeout for Defaultwebsite and my App). server timeout in server is currently set to 20 minutes.